# Comparing means on aggregated data

Tags: hypothesis-testing, inference, weighted-mean

I'm confused about how to compare means given the following scenario. Suppose a company has stores in 2 countries, CA and US, which each get some number of `Customers` who either make a purchase (`Buyers`) or don't. I want determine if the difference in `Buyers per Customer` or `Revenue per Customer` between the two countries is statistically significant. However, we don't have the customer level data, only the daily store level data.

Here is some example data for a certain time period.

```py
import pandas as pd

data = pd.DataFrame({
    'Country': ['CA']*4 + ['US']*4,
    'StoreID': range(8),
    'Customers': [1, 10, 100, 1000]*2,
    'Revenue': [20, 20, 20, 500] + [200, 200, 10, 100],
    'Buyers': [1, 2, 50, 100] + [1, 8, 2, 200],
}).set_index('StoreID')
data['Buyers per Customer'] = data['Buyers'] / data['Customers']
data['Revenue per Customer'] = data['Revenue'] / data['Customers']
data
```

```
|   StoreID | Country   |   Customers |   Revenue |   Buyers |   Buyers per Customer |   Revenue per Customer |
|----------:|:----------|------------:|----------:|---------:|----------------------:|-----------------------:|
|         0 | CA        |           1 |        20 |        1 |                  1    |                   20   |
|         1 | CA        |          10 |        20 |        2 |                  0.2  |                    2   |
|         2 | CA        |         100 |        20 |       50 |                  0.5  |                    0.2 |
|         3 | CA        |        1000 |       500 |      100 |                  0.1  |                    0.5 |
|         4 | US        |           1 |       200 |        1 |                  1    |                  200   |
|         5 | US        |          10 |       200 |        8 |                  0.8  |                   20   |
|         6 | US        |         100 |        10 |        2 |                  0.02 |                    0.1 |
|         7 | US        |        1000 |       100 |      200 |                  0.2  |                    0.1 |
```

And with mean data

```py
mean_data = data.groupby('Country').mean()
mean_data['Buyers per Customer (weighted)'] = mean_data['Buyers'] / mean_data['Customers']
mean_data['Revenue per Customer (weighted)'] = mean_data['Revenue'] / mean_data['Customers']
mean_data
```

```
| Country   |   Customers |   Revenue |   Buyers |   Buyers per Customer |   Revenue per Customer |   Buyers per Customer (weighted) |   Revenue per Customer (weighted) |
|:----------|------------:|----------:|---------:|----------------------:|-----------------------:|---------------------------------:|----------------------------------:|
| CA        |      277.75 |     140   |    38.25 |                 0.45  |                  5.675 |                         0.137714 |                          0.50405  |
| US        |      277.75 |     127.5 |    52.75 |                 0.505 |                 55.05  |                         0.189919 |                          0.459046 |
```

Specifically I am interested in inferring if the (weighted) `Buyers per Customer` or the `Revenue per Customer` are significantly different between the US and CA.

For the `Buyers per Customer` I am assuming I can do a simple proportion z test which will compare the total ratios of the Buyers to Customers between the two countries and which will also properly take into account the number of customers. Is this correct?

However for `Revenue per Customer` I'm a little unsure how to proceed. If I had the `Revenue` value for each `Customer` I would perform a t-test. However, I only have the aggregated data. Is there some inference technique that would apply here?